# Does the server record SSH tunnel traffic?

Tags: ssh, logs, ssh-tunneling

I am using an SSH Tunnel to connect to the Internet (via SOCKS). Does the server I am using records the traffic coming from my computer on any log file on the server? I mean, does my Linux server stores that my personal IP has visited Google.com via the SSH tunnel?

I am using CentOS 7. Default configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per `sshd_config` manual:

> LogLevel
> - Gives the verbosity level that is used when logging messages from sshd(8).  The possible values are: QUIET, FATAL, ERROR, INFO, VER‐BOSE, DEBUG, DEBUG1, DEBUG2, and DEBUG3. The default is INFO.  DEBUG and DEBUG1 are equivalent. DEBUG2 and DEBUG3 each specifyhigher levels of debugging output. Logging with a DEBUG level violates the privacy of users and is not recommended.`

Going through /etc/ssh/sshd_config with option `LogLevel DEBUG3`, I could see the following line after issuing the `curl` command from the local machine:

`$ curl -s --proxy socks5h://localhost:9999 http://google.com/ > /dev/null`

`sshd[1652]: debug1: connect_next: host google.com ([172.217.17.142]:80) in progress, fd=8`

And

`: debug1: channel 1: connected to google.com port 443`

Then the answer is Yes, only if we increased the debugging level.